# OneToMany collection not removing entities

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

So I've messed around with this for awhile and I can't seem to get it to work.

So adding items to the collection works fine. But removing does not seem to work at all. What do I have wrong in my mappings?

Parent element is pretty straight forward. Child element's primary key is made up of the parent id and customer id. Within a parent association, a customer can only be added once.

Any help you can provide would be greatly appreciated.

Code:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PARENT_TABLE")
public class Parent {
    private Integer parentId;
    private List<Child> children;

    @Id
    @Column(name="PARENT_ID")
    public Integer getParentId() {
        return parentId;
    }

    public void setParentId(Integer parentId) {
        this.parentId = parentId;
    }

    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="parent",orphanRemoval=true)
    public List<Child> getChildren() {
        return children;
    }

    public void setChildren(List<Child> children) {
        this.children = children;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof Parent)) return false;
        Parentt that = (Parent) o;
        return Objects.equals(getParentId(), that.getParentId());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(getParentId());
    }
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "CHILD_TABLE")
public class Child {
    private Parent parent;
    private Customer customer;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="PARENT_ID")
    public Parent getParent() {
        return parent;
    }

    public void setParent(Parent parent) {
        this.parent parent;
    }

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="CUSTOMER_ID")
    public Customer getCustomer() {
        return customer;
    }

    public void setCustomer(Customer customer) {
        this.customer = customer;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof Child)) return false;
        Child that = (Child) o;
        return Objects.equals(getParent(), that.getParent()) &&
                Objects.equals(getCustomer(), that.getCustomer());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(getParent(), getCustomer());
    }
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "CUSTOMER_TABLE")
public class Customer{
    private Integer customerId;

    @Id
   @Column(name="CUSTOMER_ID")
    public Integer getCustomerId() {
        return customerId;
    }

    public void setCustomerId(Integer customerId) {
        this.customerId = customerId;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add your code where you delete an entity

Comment: firstly add which entity you want to delete.